# drupal 8 : set twig date format to output full days and month in french

Tags: date, twig, drupal-8

{{ node.field_date_evenement_news.und[0].value2|date("m/d/Y", Europe/Paris") }}

output

```
 2/22/2016
```

i would like it to be

```
  22 février 2016
```

Comment: is your multilanguage installation properly set up? https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/d8-multi-lingual/

Comment: thanks. this can't help for me here because the content i am displaying for that module  is external to drupal and provided by a webservice

Answer (score 2):

I resolve this by creating my own **Twig Filter**.

You can do the same by creating your own module exposing this **Filter**.

Feel free to re-use it.

**Code**

```
namespace Drupal\twig_extender\TwigExtension;

class Dates extends \Twig_Extension {

    /**
    * List of all Twig functions
    */
    public function getFilters() {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('date_format', array($this, 'formatDate')),
        ];
    }

    /**
    * Unique identifier for this Twig extension
    */
    public function getName() {
        return 'twig_extender.twig.dates';
    }

    /*
    Render a custom date format with Twig
    Use the internal helper "format_date" to render the date using the current language for texts
    */
    public static function formatDate($date, $format) {
        if ($date_format = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)) {
            $timestmap = strtotime($date);
        }elseif (is_a($date, 'Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime') || is_a($date, 'DateTime')){
            $timestmap = $date->getTimestamp();
        }else{
            $timestmap = $date;
        }
        return format_date($timestmap, "custom", $format);
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
{{ my_unformatted_date|date_format('d M') }}
```

This will result to

```
01 Déc # In French
01 Dec # In English
```

**Tips**

This filter work with an input date of multiple form such:

- DateTime
- Timestamp
- Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime

Hope it will help you guy !

Answer (score 1):

- set my custom format and choose language on /admin/config/regional/date-time
- {{ date|format_date('my_format_machine_name') }}

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor update, format_date is now deprecieted, use 
    `return \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($timestamp, 'custom', $format);` instead